# How to disable checkstyle JavaDoc validation for classes?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle 2.17 in my java project. I want to ignore javadoc for all the classes and only want to enforce javadoc for interfaces. Is there any way I can do this in my xml configuration file. Right now it looks like this:

```
<!-- Javadoc for interface must be present/valid. The same for classes is optional-->
<module name="JavadocType">
        <property name="tokens" value="INTERFACE_DEF"/>
</module>
```

It works fine for interfaces but it gives error when no javadoc is specified for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct. Checkstyle has even [a test](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/871b20e88b5bfedb324f3e1996b37d0c68eb727b/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/JavadocTypeCheckTest.java#L289), confirming that no violations are reported for classes if `tokens` are set to `INTERFACE_DEF`.

Comment: Then why it is not working? I have also tried METHOD_DEF and CLASS_DEF but all in vain.

Comment: @DarshilBabel please provide exact reproducer then

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but try overriding `acceptableTokens` in your XML, instead of `tokens`.

This is how we prevent enforcing javadoc rules on class constructors. Don't forget to reference the new custom class from your `*_checks.xml` file.

```
public class JavadocMethodCheck extends com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck {

    @Override
    public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
        return Arrays.stream(super.getAcceptableTokens())
            .filter(t -> t != TokenTypes.CTOR_DEF) // Don't enforce javadoc comments on constructors
            .toArray();
    }
}
```